# Allowing only two types of user

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

This code should allow two types of use to access my page.

After I coded the second `if` statement, I could no longer access the page.

Here's my code.

```
private void AuthenticateUser()
{
    if ((string)Session["user_type"] != "user")
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/Pages/Account/Login.aspx");
    }
    if ((string)Session["user_type"] != "special_user")
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/Pages/Account/Login.aspx");
    }
}
```

What I want is to only allow two types of user `user` and `special_user` to access a certain page.

Comment: is the first statement always true? you should have special user check first and then the user check.

Comment: @user1490835 pardon?

Comment: i think your logic is all incorrect. one of the above two statements will always be true and therefore you will never be able to proceed to the website and will always be brought back to the login page as the user type will only be able to hold one value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a flaw in your logic. If you're a *"special_user"*, then the first `if` block is going to return `false` (after all, you're a *"special_user"*, not merely a *"user"*), and you get redirected.

Check for both types in a single statement:

```
var userType = (string)Session["user_type"];

if (userType != "user" && userType != "special_user")
{
    Response.Redirect("~/Pages/Account/Login.aspx");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow these user types through, you should say: `== "user")` instead of `!= "user")`, unless I'm misunderstanding your question.

Comment: Updated my question.What I want is only to allow two types of user: **user** and **special_user** to access a certain page.

Comment: Okay, the `!=` operator means "not equal to", while `==` means "equal to". By putting `!= "user"`, you are disallowing the user type from accessing the page. You should switch it as I mentioned above.

Comment: so I tried `== "user"` and `== "special_user" ` and now loads directly to the page that I am trying to access.It doesn't **Authenticate** anymore.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking then. It seems that you wanted to redirect if the user type was "user" or "special_user". So changing to the code to let those types through fixes that. It seems as though you are looking for the opposite, in which case Grant's answer makes the most sense.

Answer (score 0):

User can be "user" or "special_user". Can there be any other types of user?

This logic can be implemented in one if statement:
Check for `(user == "user" || user == "special_user")` then do something , else redirect to login page.
Or
do `(user != "user" && user != "special_user")` redirect to Login Page